# How do I leave a Mahjong game without losing all my points?

Tags: yakuza-0

I was playing a game of Mahjong at the Orchid Palace Mahjong parlor when I noticed I was up by a few thousand points. After the current hand ended I decided to quit with my winnings, only for the results screen to show I had 0 points and that I'd lost my entrance fee. My best guess is that I'd lost points for leaving the game early.

How do I leave a Mahjong game without losing all of my points? Do I need to wait for the game to end first?

[image: Losing all points in Mahjong]

Answer (score 2):

Your guess posed in the question is the correct answer; leaving a mahjong game **via the pause menu** counts as a forfeit, resulting in losing all of your points. The game will end itself after the set number of turns, which can be changed before starting. The only other way to quit out of a mahjong game without finishing it would be to force close the game, and loading a save file from before you started it.

Comment: The Change Rules menu has a "Game Style" option for "Half Game" or "Quarter Game". Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: Yes, that setting will adjust the number of "Rounds" played, but the exact number of turns depends on certain game conditions. A quarter game will typically be shorter than a half game, but there could be a time where it goes on longer.

Comment: What are the game conditions? How many "rounds" is a quarter game?

Comment: In standard Riichi Mahjong rules a quarter game has each player lead one round as dealer (a single East Wind), and a half game has each player lead two rounds as dealer (an East Wind and a South Wind). However, if the current dealer wins the round or the round ends in a draw, then another round starts with the same dealer. The game can also end if one player runs out of money, I can't remember if that applies in Yakuza 0 as well but I assume it does.